# Can't create customized Eclipse with default svn repository added

Tags: eclipse, subversive, branding

Right now I am trying to create a custom Eclipse distribution with specific predefined settings. To configure the plugins, I added some new lines to the **plugin_customization.ini** file (in the org.eclipse.epp.package.java plugin), which works well (e.g. specific formatting rules). It looks like:

> org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.line_length=120

Now the problem: I try to do the same with SVN setting. I tried to copy the settings from the

> (workspace)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.team.svn.core.prefs

file, but it does not work.

I found a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=311019) related to this problem, but it seems, that the provided test software, but it seems nonfunctioning as well.

Does there anyone out, who knows how can one define a custom svn repository (which does not disappear, when a user changes the workspace)?